# Override data annotation attributes in inherited models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I'm building mvc 5 web application, and use the following model for validation:

```
public abstract class AccountModel
{
    public abstract string Password { get; set; }
}

public class EditAccountModel : AccountModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(UsersResources), Name = "Password")]
    public override string Password { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterAccountModel : AccountModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(UsersResources), Name = "Password")]
    public override string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have base class to use it in the same edit form like this:
    @model WebApplication.AccountModel

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password)
</div>
```

but with different validation rules. Currently no client side validation working, since model is of type `AccountModel`. Is it possible to add attributes on inherited model and support client side and server side validations of asp.net mvc 5?

Comment: I think dataannotation attibute accepts only constant. In order to set it dynamically, you may need to create your own

Comment: I think the custom attributes are retrieved by evaluating the expression instead of `Model.GetType()`, perhaps 'upcasting' the  type in the expression works and you can find a way around it considering that.

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, Account Model has no data annotations, and you are using it in your view.

Have you tried making your view take RegisterAccountModel instead?

Sounds like you are trying to get reuse out of your code, but perhaps you're trying a little too hard here.  Perhaps Registration and Account management are not the same - maybe in registration you end up adding a "captcha" feature, or a "where you heard about us" option, and etc...